# How to change the dropdown button's caret symbol when clicked ? HTML CSS Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown

[image]

Suppose I have a dropdown button that looks like the picture above.

When I click on this drop down, it looks like this,

[image]

Notice, how the caret symbol "v" is still inverted.

I want that caret symbol to be "^" instead.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <button id="num-of-results-btn" data-target="#myDropdown" class="dropbtn">30 results</button>
   <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="">10 results</a>
       <a href="">20 results</a>
       <a href="">30 results</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have copied this snippet of code from the link

"https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown"

From the link above, there is no caret symbol at all.

But when I copy that code into my project, suddenly the caret symbol appears.

So, how can I located that caret symbol and manipulate it the way I described above ?

I would appreciate any pointers or tips that can throw me in the right direction.

Here is the CSS that I am applying to this code.

```
.dropbtn{
    height: 48px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: start;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width: 198px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
```

Also, my project does include the bootstrap4.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap or other external CSS libraries?

Comment: typically it would be the `:after` of the `<button>` that would have its `content` css property set with the value for the caret. But the link you provided does not use a caret in its example

Comment: *'I have copied this snippet of code from the link"* - applying the CSS in that link does not produce an output similar to that in the image.

Comment: I think it's called a chevron (not a veggie).

Comment: @BenM Yes, I am using the bootstrap. And indeed the cause of that carrot "v" symbol was from the bootstrap. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @zgood Okay, I found that my project includes the bootstrap which already defines the class name with "dropdown". So I will change the "dropdown" class to something else and use the :after. Thank you.

Comment: @Spectric I have edited the question to include my own CSS. But I found that the caret was coming from the Bootstrap class.

Comment: @wazz Sorry, I am not sure what you mean by that ? Are you referring to the carrot(caret) ? Sorry for the mis-spelling I will edit it.

Comment: *No biggie*, but yes. Shift-6 is a caret. You're dealing with a chevron; we see them on roads. Rabbits eat carrots. : )

Answer (score 0):

Something that has worked for me in the past is the following:

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

inside the menu item when the display is none use:

```
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

make a js eventlister for when the user clicks you rotate the caret.

Hope that helps.